# Browser Support Information

Tags: usability, interaction-design, popup, dialog

I am working on a web portal design and it used by enterprise admins. I am not sure which device (Laptop/PC) or which browser they are going to login and use the portal, so wanted to show the "Browser support” info.

Thought of two options,

Option 1:  Once the admin open the portal - on login page itself, displaying the browser support info in a popup upfront. Admin read the info - close the popup - go ahead and log in on same browser or uses another browser (which is supported) to login. Once logged in to the portal, the same information will be added in footer throughout the portal.

Option 2: No popup displayed upfront, browser support info will be added in the footer - in login page & in all other portal pages.

Suggestions to improve the experience to show the browser support info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there is no reason to bother the user with what's currently supported if they're already using a supported configuration. GitHub identifies the current browser configuration and if it's unsupported they notify the user and offer alternative solutions. The user may choose to continue but is accepting the risk of some features not working.

The Learn More option provides additional information if the summary text doesn't provide enough information.

[image: GitHub browser support]

Comment: I realise this question was actually asked over a year ago but the suggestion algorithm in StackExchange decided today was the day I should answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Option 1 works best because it tells right away to the user the reason why he might not have the experience he expects (buggy interface, for example), because he is using an unsupported browser/version.

To help, I found this article where it mentions how to create efficient dialog messages, depending of its context: https://uxplanet.org/5-essential-ux-rules-for-dialog-design-4de258c22116